# Google sheets: creating a sheet for verbal grading

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to create a Google spreadsheet for grading students' homework. There are 8 rubrics (columns). In each rubric, there should be three levels: "good", "mediocre", "bad". They are worth, respectively, 2 points, 1 point and 0 points. The total grade is the sum of the grades in all 8 columns.

I found [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) an explanation of how to create the dropdown list for each rubric. I created a dropdown list that contains the three options: "good", "mediocre" or "bad" (see the [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lUnNiu1ku_TpKpYNPzHxABMUlO3SpUB0jD5Dr252VyU/edit?usp=sharing)). Now I need to write a formula for the final grade. One option is to create, for each column, an auxiliary column in which the text is converted to a number, e.g. using "If" or "Switch", and then sum the values in the 8 auxiliary columns. Is there a more efficient way to do this, without using extra columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the same result with this calculation, extended to all student rows and easier to understand:

```
=if(A2:A = "" ,"",sum(switch(B2:I2,"Good",2,"Mediocre",1,0)))
```

Comment: Indeed it is much simpler, and I think I do not even need the first "IF" (I can simply copy this formula `sum(switch(B2:I2,"Good",2,"Mediocre",1,0))` to all student rows).

Comment: eliminating the IF, the extension of the calculation to one (or more) row with an empty student name would produce a sequence of useless zeros

Answer (score 2):

Try this out in J2

```
=index(if(A2:A="",,mmult(--switch(B2:I,"Good",2,"Mediocre",1,),sequence(columns(B2:I))^0)))
```

Comment: This works like a charm :-)